# No artifact feeds found in Azure DevOps

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, nuget

We are trying to push a nuget package from an Azure DevOps build pipeline to an Azure Artifacts feed. However, in the nuget push step, we're not able to select a target feed. It says "No results found.", although we have three feeds! All feeds have the Project Collection Build Service account set up for contributor privileges. The build pipeline is running in the Project Collection authorization scope.

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Comment: I've just hit the same problem and posted a question similar to yours, is this a wider fault or are we missing something?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536510/azure-devops-accessing-artifact-feed-in-release-pipeline-task

Comment: Problem has been fixed by Microsoft. Confirmed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536510/azure-devops-accessing-artifact-feed-in-release-pipeline-task