# Azure Devops - Accessing artifact feed in release pipeline task

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Nuget Push task in an Azure DevOps release definition, I also have artifact feeds but they refuse to show up as an option in the NuGet Push task:

[image: NuGet Push task]

I've checked and my user has the package management extension
[image: Package Management Extension]

I've checked that the Project Collection Build Service is a contributor on the feed:

[image: Feed Settings]

I'm on a trial license of the Package Management extension but it has 9 days remaining. So I'm at a loss as to what else I need to do to get the feed to be used in the task. Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: did this work previously? i've seen almost identical question 15 minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536165/no-artifact-feeds-found-in-azure-devops

Comment: I've never had it working but interesting someone else has asked the same question in a very short space of time!

Comment: weird, it always worked for me, didnt really see it fail\not work, sorry

Comment: Are there packages on the feed? Can you push a package to the feed with nuget cli? And of course, stupid question of questions, have you closed your browser and tried from incognito?

Comment: @JoshGust There are packages on the feed and I am able to push via the CLI. I've just tried using incognito but the same problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the one who posted the very same issue here [No artifact feeds found in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536165/no-artifact-feeds-found-in-azure-devops)

The problem seems to have been fixed now. I'm able to select my feeds. Can you confirm this, oceanexplorer?

Comment: Just tested this and it is working!! It was clearly a bug on Microsoft's side as I have done nothing but yet now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why the feed isn't showing up in the drop down like it should be, but here's a workaround.

## Create a new Service Connection

[image]

---

- Generate a new PAT with Packaging Read/Write
- Use "Basic Authentication"
- Name the service connection
- Get the url to the feed from the "Connect to this feed" menu in the artifacts area
- Use any username
- Enter the PAT

[image]

---

## Use the Service Connection as "external" feed on pipeline

[image]

Comment: Josh, thanks for detailing the workaround, much appreciated. It seems that MS clearly has a bug which has now been resolved as the feeds are now appearing without any intervention from me.